# How to add pallet collective on runtime?

Tags: pallet, crates

I am trying to import pallet-collective on runtime. Can't seem to figure out a way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this file to integrate the pallet-collective into your chain.
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs

Specifically you can use this line of code with some other changes
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1079-L1097
https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/bin/node/runtime/src/lib.rs#L1140-L1163